# C++: I am confused on how add user input into a vector of a class

Tags: c++

I have a class of customer

```
class customer{
private:
    int customer_id;
    string customer_name;
public:
    customer(int id, string name);
   //get set functions for id and name etc..
```

Then, I have a class that is a collection of the customer so

```
class customers{
private:
    vector<customer> custVector;
public:
    void add_cust(int id, string name);
    void find_customer(int);
    printCust();
};
```

The first thing I am trying to add is customers, so, I ask the user

```
void customers::add_cust(int id, string name)
{
   int id;
   string name; 

   cout << "Enter customer ID: ";
   cin >> id;
   custVector.push_back(id);

   cout << "Enter customer Name: ";
   cin >> name;
   custVector.push_back(name);
}
```

Will that properly store the id and name of the customer into the vector or not?

I would compile my program but it has so many other errors right now that I wouldn't even know where to begin.

But then how would I print the info? 
Would I need to have something in main like this

```
customers cust;

printCust(&cust);
```

to print out the info inside?

Comment: "*I would compile my program but...*" That's why you should write a [mcve] :-) For example, you don't really need the `customers` class.

Comment: If your code is full of compilation errors, it may be faster if you start from scratch... Work in small steps, and compile and run after every step. Like, step1, read id (and have debug print to show it). Step 2. Read name (and debug print it too). Step 3. Add `class customer`. Step 4, use `customer` to store id and name (and have debug prints to show them), ... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a customer to `custVec` all you need to do (assuming your constructor for `customer` is valid) is:

```
void customers::add_cust(int id, string name)
{
   int id;
   string name; 

   cout << "Enter customer ID: ";
   cin >> id;

   cout << "Enter customer Name: ";
   cin >> name;
   custVector.push_back(customer(id,name));
}
```

To answer your question about printing a customer's info, you can have a global function as you've defined, preferably a friend function (I'll leave that as research for you) such as:

```
void printCust(const customer& cst)
{
   cout<<cst.getID()<<'\t'<<cst.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition for the vector does not match with what you are trying to add to it. Consider the definition:

`vector<customer> custVector;`

Whats being added to it is:

`custVector.push_back(id);` and `custVector.push_back(name);`

Where the `id` is an `int`and the `name` is a `string` instead of a `customer` object which you have defined your `vector` to contain.

To correct this define a constructor in your `customer` class which initializes a `customer` object

```
customer(int id, string name) : customer_id(id), customer_name(name) { }
```

In your add function you push the `customer` objects after getting the input as:

```
custVector.push_back(customer(id, name));
```

Also try getting hold of a good beginner c++ book.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the responsibility of `add_cust()` to prompt the user for input. It is being passed input parameters from the caller. So, the parameters should be used as-is. The caller should handle prompting the user as needed, and then pass the input values to `add_cust()`.

And no, the code you have shown won't work anyway. The constructor of the `customer` class requires 2 input parameters, but you are constructing 2 separate `customer` objects with 1 input value each.

Use something more like this instead:

```
void customers::add_cust(int id, string name)
{
    custVector.push_back(customer(id, name));
}
```

Then the caller can do this:

```
customers cust;
...
int id;
string name;
cout << "Enter customer ID: ";
cin >> id;
cout << "Enter customer Name: ";
cin >> name;
cust.add_cust(id, name);
```

Then, to print the entries, simply call the class method you already defined:

```
cust.printCust();
```

Where the implementation may look like this:

```
void customers::printCust()
{
    for(vector<customer>::iterator iter =  custVector.begin(); iter != custVector.end(); ++iter) {
        cout << "id: " << iter->getID() << ", name: " << iter->getName() << endl;
    }
}
```